# mavens mate save to active org

Tags: apex, deployment, mavensmate

Setting "mm_compile_with_tooling_api" set to false allows me to change and save apex classes on even production org. I found it useful when i have quick small fix to publish but i wanted to ask is it right way to patch quick fix and how does it works behind the seens?
Also what features i miss when i have "mm_compile_with_tooling_api" set to false

```
//set to true to use the tooling api to compile apex metadata (if you're experiencing any compile issues, set this to false to use the metadata api)
"mm_compile_with_tooling_api" : false,
```

Comment: Wow - are you sure you can do this? I thought that was locked down.

Comment: Yes i am using it daily i now i am getting use to it. l0l 
Only reason i learned about sandboxes was to write apex :)